# IronPdf Print to Margin

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument, ironpdf

I try to print a pdf with [IronPdf](https://ironpdf.com/tutorials/html-to-pdf/) from html but the result leaves a border.
Is there a way to set Fit-To-Page in my PrintDocument?

Here my code:

```
        public static void PrintDocument(string printer, bool landscape, PdfDocument pdfDocument, Duplexing duplex)
        {
            var printDocument = pdfDocument.GetPrintDocument();

            printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
            printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = landscape;
            printDocument.PrinterSettings.Duplex = DuplexMapping(duplex);
            printDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4;

            printDocument.Print();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to IronPdf-Support I found a solution:

```
            // enable javascript 
            var renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
            renderer.PrintOptions.EnableJavaScript = true;
            renderer.PrintOptions.RenderDelay = 500; //milliseconds
            renderer.PrintOptions.CssMediaType = IronPdf.PdfPrintOptions.PdfCssMediaType.Screen;

            renderer.PrintOptions.MarginTop = 0;
            renderer.PrintOptions.MarginBottom = 0;
            renderer.PrintOptions.MarginLeft = 0;
            renderer.PrintOptions.MarginRight = 0;
```

Set Margin to 0.

Comment: Useful!

API documentation can be found at  https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.PdfPrintOptions.html#IronPdf_PdfPrintOptions_MarginBottom

Comment: PrintOptions are now RenderingOptions